# Playa jquery error

Tags: playa, error, javascript

is anyone else getting an error in jquery when using playa in single entry mode?
The error is:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{DEFAULT} -> jquery.js:23`

multiple entry selection mode works fine.

All the functionality still seems to work except the built in search/filter.

EE 2.9.0
playa 4.5.1

other misc addons(yes, there may be some out of date ones there):

- bridge
- bw_category_count
- child_categories
- cookie_plus
- developer
- devotee
- dm_shortee
- fieldpack
- freebie
- freeform
- fusion
- human_filesize
- img_download_sizer
- imgsizer
- low_seg2cat
- matrix
- mx_cloner
- mx_title_control
- pagination
- power_truncate
- pt_dropdown
- pt_field_pack
- pt_list
- pt_switch
- selectatron_migrator
- the_selectatron
- url_encode
- url_tube
- wygwam
- youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug - already fixed locally. We will be getting an update out later this week to address it.